# Selection sort not printing correct result

Tags: python, data-structures, selection-sort

I'm trying to implement selection sort in python using a list. But the implementation part is correct and is as per my algorithm but it is not resulting in correct output. Adding my code:

```
my_list = [64, 25, 12, 11, 32]

def selection_sort(element_list):
    for element in range(len(element_list)):
        mindex = element
        for compare_index in range(element+1, len(element_list)):
            if element_list[mindex] > element_list[compare_index]:
                mindex = compare_index
        element_list[compare_index], element_list[mindex] = element_list[mindex], element_list[compare_index]

    for element in range(len(element_list)):
        print(element_list[element])

selection_sort(my_list)
```

desired output:

```
11
12
25
32
64
```

May I know where I'm making mistake?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: How do you know that the implementation is correct if the output is incorrect?

Comment: @LearningMathematics, do you want me to add the algorithm in detail?

Comment: @U12-Forward added.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = [64, 25, 12, 11, 32]

def selection_sort(element_list):
    for element in range(len(element_list)):
        mindex = element
        for compare_index in range(element+1, len(element_list)):
            if element_list[mindex] > element_list[compare_index]:
                mindex = compare_index
        element_list[element], element_list[mindex] = element_list[mindex], element_list[element]

    for element in range(len(element_list)):
        print(element_list[element])

selection_sort(my_list)
```

I would recommend using i and j instead of element and compare_index.

Look at line 9. Why does that fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is almost correct but
`element_list[compare_index], element_list[mindex] = element_list[mindex], element_list[compare_index]` in this line you made the mistake.
It shouldn't be `compare_index`, it should be `element`. Please check the correct algorithm below

```
my_list = [64, 25, 12, 11, 32]

def selection_sort(element_list):
    for element in range(len(element_list)):
        mindex = element
        for compare_index in range(element+1, len(element_list)):
            if element_list[mindex] > element_list[compare_index]:
                mindex = compare_index
        element_list[element], element_list[mindex] = element_list[mindex], element_list[element]

    for element in range(len(element_list)):
        print(element_list[element])

selection_sort(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    my_list = [64, 25, 12, 11, 32]
    
    def selection_sort(element_list):
        for element in range(len(element_list)):
            mindex = element
            for compare_index in range(element+1, len(element_list)):
                if element_list[mindex] > element_list[compare_index]:
                    mindex = compare_index
            element_list[element], element_list[mindex] = element_list[mindex],element_list[element]

        for element in range(len(element_list)):
            print(element_list[element])


    selection_sort(my_list)
```

swapping is a must between `element_list[element]` and  `element_list[mindex]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the line

`element_list[compare_index], element_list[mindex] = element_list[mindex], element_list[compare_index]`

Here I believe you want to exchange the position of the bigger and the smaller number in the array, but the problem is that you are exchanging the positions of the elements with indexes `compare_index` and `mindex`. And in the very previous line you are doing `mindex = compare_index` so basically you are exchanging one element with itself.

Rather, you must exchange elements with indexes `element` and `mindex`, as `compare_index` is just for temporary use.

Make this change in that line:

`element_list[element], element_list[mindex] = element_list[mindex], element_list[element]`

I hope this solves your problem!